# How to make an overflow object scrollable or start from the right?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, overflow, heatmap

I am trying to recreate github's heatmap. I am using a package from [uiws](https://github.com/uiwjs/react-heat-map) to build the heatmap, however, on smaller screen I would like either make the heat map scrollable in the x-direction or have the heatmap start from the right hand edge so the latest dates are shown. See the below images to get a better idea of what I mean.

My current approach is to set the width of the heatmap to a set width, say 700px and `overflow:hidden` it when the screensize decreases. However, with this approach, when the screen width decreases, the right side of the heatmap gets cut off. I would like for the left hand side to get cut off. Alternativly, this could be scrollable left and right, but I wasn't able to implement that when I tried `overflow: scroll`.

Github's approach, when I dug into the inspector tools, was to set the container around the heatmap to `flex` and `align-items:flex-end`, but when I tried this for my solution, the heatmap did not shift to the right.

This is a link to a striped down version on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-dew-z9gi9?file=/src/App.js)

As you can see in the image, the latest dates are pushed to the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
div.scrollArea {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I have, I still get the same effect